# can't play video with local file in android

Tags: html, ionic-framework

i have avi file in local file directory
file:///storage/emulated/0/ionic_download/2022-02-07/18/18-59-32.avi
but the problem is that I want to play video with above file path.

data[i].toURL() is above file path

html

```
 <video controls autoplay width="{{top_box_width}}" height="{{top_box_height}}">
        <source [src]="play_path" type="video/mp4">
        
      </video>
```

.ts

```
let myURL = normalizeURL(data[i].toURL() ) + "#t=0.1";
          console.log("222"+myURL);
          this.play_path = this.sanitizer.bypassSecurityTrustResourceUrl(data[i].toURL());
         
          console.log('Cccccontent path cahnged ', this.play_path);
          this.dismiss_loading();
```

both myURL and play_path is not playing video…
how can I play video?
thank you

chorme://inspect result is

[image]

[image]

what is really weird for me is that with fileopener.open
it works. so file path is not wrong or not found

```
   this.fileOpener.open("file:///storage/emulated/0/ionic_download/2022-02-07/18/18-59-32.avi", 'video/mp4')
    .then(() => console.log('File is opened'))
    .catch(e => {
      console.log('Error opening file', e);
      if(e.message == "File not found"){
        alert("파일이 없습니다.");
        this.localstorage_remove(file_name);
      }
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK you should not define `savePath` inside functions. Your html code cannot even find the variable `savePath` because its being defined and initialized much later after the whole HTML has been rendered.

Define your `savePath` variable as global then initialize it inside your function using `this.savePath`. Your code should work.

Comment: *.ts
          let myURL = normalizeURL(data[i].toURL() ) + "#t=0.1";
          console.log("222"+myURL);
          this.play_path = this.sanitizer.bypassSecurityTrustResourceUrl(data[i].toURL());
          // this.play_path = myURL
          // document.getElementById('video').setAttribute('src', this.play_path);
          console.log('Cccccontent path cahnged ', this.play_path);
          this.dismiss_loading();

Comment: *.html

      <video controls autoplay width="{{top_box_width}}" height="{{top_box_height}}">
        <source [src]="play_path" type="video/mp4">
        
      </video>

but it's same.

Comment: Please edit your question @pedroj, code in comments is unreadable.

Comment: ok I edited! thank you ! also I added photo !

Comment: Please put an ngIf="play_path" within your  <video> tag, so that the video tag will only appear / play only if there is data inside the src path.

Comment: yes I already add in upper tree of video tag...I already upload video that video tag have file path(on second image I uploaded)

Comment: Do some tests, put the video file directly in your ionic's assets path and see if the video detects it. Also try without using file:// see what works. 

Some paths may not be accessible from ionic. Here are some paths that can help: https://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/latest/reference/cordova-plugin-file/index.html

Comment: what is weired is that with fileopener with same hardcoded file path, it works.

Comment: Its better you adopt an open standard where to store your video files because as Android versions keeps incrementing, they become more strict on where you store files and how you access them. 

Paths that were available back in Android 9 may no longer work in Android 12.